# Loading external dll with bridj is not possible due to hebrew username

Tags: java, path, loading, hebrew, bridj

I tried to load native library (*lib.dll*) to Java application via BridJ on Windows 7, where username is written in Hebrew.

What is important is that the Java application downloads *lib.dll* and save it properly in place:

```
C:\Users\דני\AppData\Local\Temp\lib.dll
```

I have reference to that file -> File lib, and pass `lib.getCanonicalPath()` to BridJ.

In the end I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Library 'LIB' was not found in path
...
...
...
(failed to load C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Temp\lib.dll)
at org.bridj.BridJ.getNativeLibrary(BridJ.java:619)
at org.bridj.BridJ.getNativeLibrary(BridJ.java:619)
at org.bridj.BridJ.getNativeLibrary(BridJ.java:599)
at org.bridj.BridJ.getNativeLibrary(BridJ.java:315)
at org.bridj.CRuntime.getNativeLibrary(CRuntime.java:341)
at org.bridj.CRuntime.register(CRuntime.java:299)
... 21 more
```

So it seems that, `getCanonicalPath()` converts דני to.

How can I solve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug looks similar to the following issue, which was fixed yesterday :

https://github.com/ochafik/nativelibs4java/issues/276

You might want to try again with the latest 0.7-SNAPSHOT.